# Android dialog on click take full screen (minus the keyboard)

Tags: android, user-interface, dialog, customdialog

[image]

ok so I have a custom dialog that it shows up as the left picture. And I want with a click of a button (black square) to take the full screen like the right screen but don't go behind the keyboard. How can I do this?

for now my dialog is like this

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/comments_relative_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#FFFFFF" >
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/user_comments"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/char_count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="2048" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/full_screen_button_selector"
        android:minHeight="1dp"
        android:minWidth="1dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried this on onclick but it doesn't work

```
RelativeLayout r = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.comments_relative_layout);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams _rootLayoutParams = new     
FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
r.setLayoutParams(_rootLayoutParams);
```

anyone has an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
myDialog.show();
Window window = myDialog.getWindow();
window.setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```

Comment: That is correct! I used that and after i also changed programmatically a little bit the layout (added some rules, above , below etc.. ) and it works great! thank you

Comment: Could you please share the code to me. I want same layout.